# How to groupby then sortBy using string from nested data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm trying to first group and then sort using a nested property to recreate an array. So far I can groupBy fine but sort is not working for me.
Below is a sample of data I'm working with.

`

```
let arr = [
      {
        'id': 6,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 1,
          'start': '08:00:00',
          'end': '09:10:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 7,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 2,
          'start': '07:00:00',
          'end': '08:30:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 8,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 3,
          'start': '02:00:00',
          'end': '03:00:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 9,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 5,
          'start': '04:00:00',
          'end': '05:10:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 10,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 1,
          'start': '08:00:00',
          'end': '09:10:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 11,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 2,
          'start': '07:00:00',
          'end': '08:30:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 12,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 3,
          'start': '02:00:00',
          'end': '03:00:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 13,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 5,
          'start': '04:00:00',
          'end': '05:10:00'
        }
      }
    ]
```

`

I am using lodash to group and sort. Below is the desired result which is grouped using `date` and then sorted using the `start` value .
**Expected result:**
`

```
let groupedAndSortedArr =
    [
      {
        'id': 8,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 3,
          'start': '02:00:00',
          'end': '03:00:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 9,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 5,
          'start': '04:00:00',
          'end': '05:10:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 7,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 2,
          'start': '07:00:00',
          'end': '08:30:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'date': '2019-05-06',
        'time': {
          'id': 1,
          'start': '08:00:00',
          'end': '09:10:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 12,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 3,
          'start': '02:00:00',
          'end': '03:00:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 13,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 5,
          'start': '04:00:00',
          'end': '05:10:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 11,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 2,
          'start': '07:00:00',
          'end': '08:30:00'
        }
      },
      {
        'id': 10,
        'date': '2019-05-07',
        'time': {
          'id': 1,
          'start': '08:00:00',
          'end': '09:10:00'
        }
      }
    ]
```

`

I have tried using `_.mapValues(_.groupBy(arr, 'date'), t => _.sortBy(t, 'start'))` which groups but does not correctly sort by `start` time .
What could be a good way to achieve this result?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be `_.sortBy(t, 'time.start')`?

Comment: Ah you're right. Guess I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out